# How do I iterate through a file and count the number of times each character shows up?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

```bsh
function count{
  declare -a array 

  for((i=0; i<256;i++)); do
    ${array[$i]}=0
  done

  while read line_in; do
    ((line_num++))

    ...(Code Needed)

    if [ $line_num == 100 ]; then 
      break
    fi
  done < "${path_in}"
(Code needed to print the counts)
```

How would I complete this function by iterate through each lines of the file and count the number of a certain character appearance and print it out?

Given a text file, I want to iterate through the file and for each line, I want to count the number of each ASCll letter occurrence and store it inside a array. Then I would output each element in the array with the counts. Upper and lower case are treated the same.

Input:

```
Hello 
world
```

Expected output:

```
D:1
H:1
E:1
L:3
O:2
R:1
W:1
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Perhaps you could edit you post to explain in some more detail what you are trying to accomplish? Your sample code looks like a rather incomplete excerpt and is therefore difficult to analyze.

Comment: You say: "for each line", but then give an example output that is for the whole file. And also clarify. Do you need the array or just the output?

Answer (score 4):

In order to count each character in file with `GNU awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){a[$i]++}}END{for (i in a){print i,":", a[i]}}' file
```

To treat characters case-insensitive `tolower` or `toupper` can be used

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){a[tolower($i)]++}}END{for (i in a){print i,":", a[i]}}' file
```

sample output

```
c : 1
d : 3
e : 2
f : 2
h : 1
i : 12
l : 1
m : 1
n : 8
o : 2
p : 1
r : 4
s : 1
t : 6
u : 2
{ : 3
} : 3
```

Comment: I upvoted this, but it should be mentioned that empty `FS` is undefined behavior according to POSIX.

Comment: @Quasímodo thanks, so what can be used instead? any workaround?

Comment: You're welcome. I think there is one but I always seem to forget how it goes... It may be contained in Gawk's manual.

Comment: @Quasímodo I doubt that, because GNU awk is _the_ implementation which accepts an empty field separator ..

Comment: Yep, just looked it up. The Gawk manual covers only its own mechanism in Sect. 4.5.3 "Making each character a separate field" ...

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with something like this:

```
grep -o . file | sort | uniq -c

  1 d
  1 e
  1 H
  3 l
  2 o
  1 r
  1 W
```

or if you want to treat upper- and lower-case as single character:

```
grep -o . file | sort | uniq -ic | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]

  1 D
  1 E
  1 H
  3 L
  2 O
  1 R
  1 W
```

`| tr [:lower:] [:upper:]` is optional to print all upper-case as your expected output.

Comment: I needed to complete the function. I was wondering how would I declare an array with 256 ASCll values and how would I write a for loops or while loops that could iterate through each line and count the number occurrence of each letter. Sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: Why do you need to "complete the function"? Is it a school assignment?

Answer (score 1):

While I prefer the other answers, I missed a portable one, so using any awk:

```
awk '
{
    m=1
    #$0=toupper($0)
    while(m<=length($0)){ #While there are still chars unparsed in the line
        ch=substr($0,m,1) #Get one char of the line
        cnt[ch]++         #Increment its counter
        m++               #Point to the next char
    }
}
END{for(ch in cnt)print cnt[ch],"\t",ch}
' file
```

Uncomment the commented line to make the counting case insensitive.

Output on sample file:

```
1        h
1        w
3        l
2        o
1        d
1        r
1        e
```